# How to setup github.com like username url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-url

I've seen and googled and found many pretty url links.

But they all seem to look like http://example.com/users/username

I want it to be like github style http://example.com/username

Any directions that I can follow??

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with http://example.com/users/username?  The problem with using http://example.com/username is that someone could very easily register the username `admin` or `faq` which could conflict with your other routes.  You'll need to keep a list of prohibited usernames and also you'll need to check if a user exists with a given name before you create a new route, as that might conflict with an existing user.

You could always shorten it to: http://example.com/u/username.

However, if you must do this you can use `map.connect` as others have suggested, but you should definitely think about the pros and cons and whether or not it adds any significant value.

Comment: To be fair you should always have a username blacklist because a user named admin or webmaster is a bad no matter what never mind simply conflicting with routes.

Comment: Yup, but I've found this solution here http://henrik.nyh.se/2008/10/validating-slugs-against-existing-routes-in-rails
I think I'll go with this solution.

Comment: I'm glad you've found something that works for you.  Make sure when you introduce a new route you do the inverse check.

Answer (score 1):

A very Basic example could be this:

- declare a route with lowest priority pointing to your users controller's show action
- modify the show action to find records based on username

In `config/routes.rb`:

```
map.username '/:username', :controller => :users, :action => :show
```

In `UsersController`:

```
def show
  @name = Name.find_by_name(params[:username]) || Name.find(params[:id])
end
```

You can then use `username_path(:username => user.name)` to generate links.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that you just need to drop `users/` in routes?

`map.connect '/:username',...` instead of `map.connect '/users/:username',...`